# Change icon on click using angular-google-maps

Tags: angularjs

I have a number of markers on a map using angular-google-maps.
Can someone please tell me how to you change the icon image of a marker when you click on it?

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="map-wrapper" flex>
                <ui-gmap-google-map flex center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' class="ui-gmap-google-map" control="control">
                    <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" doRebuildAll="true"></ui-gmap-markers>
                </ui-gmap-google-map>
            </div>
```

My controller code to populate markers:

```
function mapFilter(dealerList) {
            angular.forEach(dealerList, function (dlr) {
                if (dlr.Category_type_id == $scope.categoryType) {
                    var marker = {
                        id: dlr.Site_owner_id + "_" + dlr.Site_locationseq,
                        icon: "/img/dealerlocator/pin_icon.png",
                        events: {
                            click: function (marker, eventName, model, arguments) {
                                gotoAnchor(marker.key);
                            }
                        },
                        latitude: dlr.Site_address_map_latitude,
                        longitude: dlr.Site_address_map_longitude,
                        showWindow: false
                    };

                    $scope.markers.push(marker);
                }

            });
        }


function gotoAnchor(x) {
            var newHash = 'anchor_' + x;
            if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
                // set the $location.hash to `newHash` and
                // $anchorScroll will automatically scroll to it
                $location.hash('anchor_' + x);

                // Update the map marker icons
                angular.forEach($scope.markers, function (mkr) {
                    if (mkr.id == x) {
                        mkr.icon = "/img/dealerlocator/pin_icon_selected.png";
                    } else {
                        mkr.icon = "/img/dealerlocator/pin_icon.png";
                    }
                });

                expandDealer(x);


            } else {
                // call $anchorScroll() explicitly,
                // since $location.hash hasn't changed
                $anchorScroll();
                expandDealer(x);
            }
        };
```

In the gotoAnchor function above, you can see here that I've changed the icon in the markers, but this doesn't change on the map.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to debug your `($location.hash() !== newHash)` to see if its making it through to the `forEach`.  [This plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/I5vhp2mNW38uzQCnDBa7?p=preview) implements the method below, and the icons are updating on click;

```
function gotoAnchor(x) {
  // Update the map marker icons
  angular.forEach($scope.randomMarkers, function (mkr) {
      if (mkr.id == x) {
          mkr.icon = "https://mapicons.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/uploads/mapicons/shape-default/color-ffc11f/shapecolor-color/shadow-1/border-dark/symbolstyle-white/symbolshadowstyle-dark/gradient-no/cserkesz_ikon.png";
      } else {
          mkr.icon = 'https://mapicons.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/uploads/mapicons/shape-default/color-128e4d/shapecolor-color/shadow-1/border-dark/symbolstyle-white/symbolshadowstyle-dark/gradient-no/crow2.png';
      }
  });
};
```

Comment: I've discovered that my code is making the forEach, however, the map page is reloaded/refreshed when I click on a marker (as I want a div to scroll to the appropriate information). When I click on the same marker a second time, it changes color. Any idea why the page refresh would happen?

Comment: You'll need to pinpoint when the refresh is occurring.  Perhaps by placing a breakpoint on `gotoAnchor()` and stepping through.  Try post a demo maybe?

Comment: I have my code in .net, so all the javascript is on one line. I've put some alerts in to see where the refresh happens, and it happens after the gotoAnchor(marker.key) function call in the marker object.

Comment: I found out that I needed the following code in my controller to prevent the page reloading. 
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
});